# Degeneracy and the unitarity of a gauge theory with a non-compact gauge group

Tags: research-level, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory, ground-state

The topological ground state degeneracy(g.s.d.) provides useful information for a topological field theory(TQFT), such as [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92809/topological-ground-state-degeneracy-of-sun-son-spn-chern-simons-theory) shows some example.

To **count g.s.d.**, it seems to be equivalent to **count the volume of the symplectic phase space**. As I have heard, it is known that a gauge theory with a non-compact gauge group the g.s.d. is infinity:
$$
\text{g.s.d.}=\infty
$$
(specifically, my interest can be 2+1D Chern-Simons theory; or other cases).

Question 1: Are there some explicit ways to demonstrate this $
\text{g.s.d.}=\infty
$?

Question 2: Does **non-compact** gauge group necessarily(only if)/sufficiently(if) leads to a **non-unitary theory**?

Many thanks.

Comment: For the question 2, non-compact groups have infinite unitary representations, so I don't think that this is contradictory with unitarity.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading Witten's _Quantization of Chern-Simons gauge theory with complex gauge group_.  (This is a special case of a general princple:  If you are working in a subject Witten has touched, you should read his papers on the subject.)