# Chiral Spin Liquid(CSL), Chern number, and the ground state degeneracy(GSD)

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-order, spin-models, chirality, topological-phase

Consider a 2D *gapped* CSL with a *nonzero* Chern number $m$, then is the GSD of the system on a torus directly related to the Chern number $m$?

For example, see [this article](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v85/i19/e195126), in the last paragraph on page 7, the authors give the **4-fold GSD** from the Chern number $m=\pm2$ for a CSL. I can not understand the explanation, can anybody present an intuitive illustration or a simple mathematical proof ? I will be very appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Free arXiv version: http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.0116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the paper, the answer is $|m|^2$. They  suggest in their p.8, Eq.36, the effective theory is a Chern-Simons theory
$$
\frac{1}{4\pi}\int K_{IJ} a_I \wedge d a_J
$$
with the $ K_{IJ}$ bilinear K matrix as
$$K_{IJ}={\begin{pmatrix}m & 0\\ 0 & -m\end{pmatrix}}$$.

The up $m$ labels one sector and the lower $m$ labels the other sector. The degeneracy(GSD) is computed by a generalizing level-$k$ U(1) Chern-Simons theory(GSD=$k$) to a bilinear K matrix U(1)$^n$ Chern-Simons theory. GSD=$|\det(K)|=|m|^2$. [This GSD result for  GSD=$|\det(K)|$ is a well-known fact](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92809/topological-ground-state-degeneracy-of-sun-son-spn-chern-simons-theory?rq=1).

Comment: @ Idear I believe your answer is correct even though I don't know about the Chern-Simons theory.... So do we have an alternative algebraic or Hamiltonian approach to understand the GSD?

Comment: Yes, a good question. the 1-form $a$ field represents so-called Wilson-line operator or simply anyons. In the lattice model, this Wilson-line operator or anyons can be regarded as the string or cycle on the lattice(such as string-net or toric-code, etc), See for example, page 4 of [this paper: Boundary Degeneracy of Topological Order - Sec: Mutual Chern-Simons, Zk gauge theory, Toric code and String-net model](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4863) and [this paper: Quantum codes on a lattice with boundary](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9811052)