# $\text{SO}(N)_1$ Chern-Simons theory has no topological order?

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order

According to appendix C5 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04251.pdf), $\text{SO}(N)_1$ Chern-Simons theory has no topological order. On the other hand, in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9811111.pdf), Prof. Wen showed $\text{SO}(5)_m$ CS theory has the ground state degeneracy (GSD) on torus $= (m+1)(m+2)/2$ and thus $\text{GSD}=3$ for $\text{SO}(5)_1$ theory. This computation is consistent with [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92809/topological-ground-state-degeneracy-of-sun-son-spn-chern-simons-theory). I wonder how to resolve the contradiction. How do you compute GSD for $\text{SO}(N)_1$ CS theory to show $\text{GSD}=1$?

Comment: Please consider spelling out abbreviations (GSD) and explaining what you mean by the subscript on the $\mathrm{SO}(N)$ to make this post more accessible.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Answer (score 3):

Many field theories are not well defined. The $SO(N)_1$ CS theory in one paper
may not be the same as the  $SO(N)_1$ CS theory in another paper.

In my paper, the full theory is fermions coupled to $SO(5)$ gauge field.
After integrating out the fermions, we get an effective $SO(5)_1$ CS theory.
Its properties are given here https://www.math.ksu.edu/~gerald/voas/mtc/kmB2_1.html .

Comment: Thank you, Prof. Wen. I am confused about the gauge group of (69) in your paper, where the gauge group is generated by sp4 Lie algebra. At the algebra level, sp4~so(5) but at the group level, SO(5) is not simply connected while Sp4 is. I wonder why the resulting theory after integrating the fermions is SO(5) CS theory instead of Sp4 CS theory.